# In emacs python-mode customize multi-line statement indentation

Tags: python, emacs

I am using the python-mode shipped with emacs 23. I want to customize the auto-indentation of mult-line statements. For example currently emacs prefers the following

```
my_var = [
    'val1',
    'val2',
    'val3',
    ]
```

I would prefer

```
my_var = [
    'val1',
    'val2',
    'val3',
]
```

Also, when creating functions with a trailing list or dict emacs prefers

```
my_func('first_arg', 'another_arg', {
        'key1': val1,
        'key2': val2,
        })
```

I would like to see

```
my_func('first_arg', 'another_arg', {
    'key1': val1,
    'key2': val2,
})
```

Is it possible to create these customizations to python-mode in emacs? I am not able to find any documentation creating these customizations.

Comment: I usually just press `TAB` repeatedly until it stops at a desired position.

Comment: That will not work for the extra lines in a multi-line statement.

Comment: You only need to press `TAB` for the first and the last line of a multiline statement. The first line sets indent for all the following lines and you press `TAB` at the last line to change the indent of closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 11):

Something like this, perhaps?

```lisp
(defadvice python-calculate-indentation (around outdent-closing-brackets)
  "Handle lines beginning with a closing bracket and indent them so that
they line up with the line containing the corresponding opening bracket."
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (let ((syntax (syntax-ppss)))
      (if (and (not (eq 'string (syntax-ppss-context syntax)))
               (python-continuation-line-p)
               (cadr syntax)
               (skip-syntax-forward "-")
               (looking-at "\\s)"))
          (progn
            (forward-char 1)
            (ignore-errors (backward-sexp))
            (setq ad-return-value (current-indentation)))
        ad-do-it))))

(ad-activate 'python-calculate-indentation)
```

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057988/multi-lines-python-indentation-on-emacs/) for a discussion of some of the Emacs features used in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at python-mode.el at the function py-indent-line.